# Permutation without recursion?

Tags: c++, permutation, non-recursive

I was trying to use a for loop to replace the recursion that I usually use, but I found it's harder than I thought. Can anyone tell me how to do it? Thanks!

For example, given a vector of 2, 1, 3. There should be six permutations:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

The vector is below...

```
vector<int> simple;
simple.push_back(2);
simple.push_back(1);
simple.push_back(3);
```

EDIT: changed the order from 1 2 3 to random order 2 1 3

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Use [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: in case you want to use boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iterator/doc/permutation_iterator.html

Comment: @PeterWood  It seems next_permutation requires the input to be in order?

Comment: @Arch1tect Yes, to get all permutations the easiest way, it needs to be sorted to start with.

Comment: @PeterWood But it doesn't need to be sorted if I use recursion method, does this mean generating permutation should always be done by recursion, and that's what most people do? (since if sorting is needed , it's slower) I'm learning so I'd love to know the way people do in practice. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [`std::next_permutation()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> simple{1, 2, 3};

    do
    {
        for (auto e : simple) { std::cout << e << " "; }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    while (next_permutation(simple.begin(), simple.end()));
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24454).

If you do not want to start with a sorted vector, you can use `std::next_permutation()` the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

constexpr int factorial(int i)
{
    return i == 0 ? 1 : i * factorial(i-1);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> simple{3, 1, 2};

    for (int i = 0; i < factorial(simple.size()); i++)
    {
        std::next_permutation(simple.begin(), simple.end());
        for (auto e : simple) { std::cout << e << " "; }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24463).

Notice, that if the size of the vector is known at compile-time, as seems to be the case from your example, you could use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of `std::vector`, as shown in [this live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24464).

Comment: it seems next_permutation requires the input to be in order?

Comment: @Arch1tect: Kind of, you're right. If you want all permutations to be found before `next_permutation` returns `false`, then yes.

Comment: I was only using 1 2 3 as an example, the vector doesn't have to be in order. Any idea how to solve in this case? Thanks anyway.:)

Comment: `factorial` won't be what you want if there are duplicates in the vector.

Comment: @PeterWood: True, although that does not seem to be the OP's use case

Comment: Thank you, took me some time to understand the algorithm.. I feel this is slower than the recursion method(using a stack and queue), since next_next_permutation takes some time. Am I right? or it's the same complexity as recursion method?

Comment: @Arch1tect: It may be slower, the link in my answer shows the complexity and a possible implementation. However, you should not be concerned with optimization unless you find out that performance is really an issue for your use case - most of the time, programmers tend to prematurely optimize their algorithms and data structures, compromising readability and elegance. Unless you have a real reason to worry about it, favor  simplicity.